# How to avoid sending a Guzzle request after instantiation?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

**Context:** Laravel 5. Guzzle ~5.2. PHP 5.4. I'm building a class to interact with an external API. I'm providing this class with a Guzzle client using a Service Provider, to avoid instantiating the client within a method.

I want to cache the results. If the user is asking for something that is found in the cache, return it instead of performing a request to said API.

**Problem: If I build up a Guzzle client and don't perform a request, the application crashes.** Not even a stack trace from PHP. Actually, if I'm using Laravel's `artisan serve`, a Windows error message shows up saying, PHP CLI has stopped working.

For now, I'm passing the Guzzle client to the method on my class, every single time I call it.

Is there a way to just instantiate the Guzzle client without sending a request? What other route would you choose to achieve this? Is that intended behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr RTM

Longer version (from the docs):

Creating Requests
You can create a request without sending it. This is useful for building up requests over time or sending requests in concurrently.

```
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', [
    'headers' => ['X-Foo' => 'Bar']
]);
```

// Modify the request as needed

```
$request->setHeader('Baz', 'bar');
```

After creating a request, you can send it with the client’s send() method.

```
$response = $client->send($request);
```

Comment: this is wrong, doesn't work. Client has no function `createRequest`

Answer (score 1):

from here:
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-a-request

```
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client([
    // Base URI is used with relative requests
    'base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org',
    // You can set any number of default request options.
    'timeout'  => 2.0,
]);

    $request = new Request('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put');
    $response = $client->send($request, ['timeout' => 2]);
```